# Two crefname for the same item

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, cleveref, amsthm

I would like to make this procedure faster. I have a `theorem` with its `crefname`. In this theorem, I have an enumerated list. I want to associate to each item two different labels, in order to produce the following result
[image]

with a code like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=citegreen, %
linkcolor=red,urlcolor=blue, unicode,psdextra,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}[section]{Theorem}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{enumi}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem}
This theorem contains some items
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic{enumi})]
    \item \label{item:theorem_1} This is the first item. %%<- It is also 
 %%ok if you have to specify the second label, 
 %%like this \item \label{item:theorem_1}\label{thm:theorem_1} This is the first item.
    \item This is the second item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\proof We can prove \cref{item:theorem_1}. \endproof 
In \cref{thm:theorem} we have \cref{thm:theorem_1,thm:theorem_2}. 
\end{document}
```

The code generate two different references, the first one includes the `theorem` label, the second one it does not. It is better if one of the two label is automatically generated, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to issue two `\label` commands, with slightly different cross-reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=citegreen,
  linkcolor=red,
  urlcolor=blue,
  unicode,
  psdextra,
  hypertexnames=false
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}[section]{Theorem}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemlabel}[4]{%
  % #1 = parent counter
  % #2 = prefix for item label
  % #3 = prefix for parent counter label
  % #4 = label
  \label{#2:#4}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname the#1\endcsname\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname}
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [#1][\arabic{#1}][]{\csname the#1\endcsname\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname}%
  }%
  \label{#3:#4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem}
This theorem contains some items
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\arabic*),ref=(\arabic*)]
    \item \itemlabel{theorem}{item}{thm}{theorem_1}
    This is the first item.

    \item \itemlabel{theorem}{item}{thm}{theorem_2}
    This is the second item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
We can prove \cref{item:theorem_1}.
\end{proof}

In \cref{thm:theorem} we have \cref{thm:theorem_1,thm:theorem_2}.

Also \ref{thm:theorem} and \ref{thm:theorem_1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware: `\proof...\endproof` is wrong and can have unpredictable consequences.

Comment: What if theorems are numbered within sections? Second squared parentheses in the label definition cause an error since it is not a number, how do you solve this?

Comment: @LucaBenatti Look at the new version

Answer (score 5):

I think this is one type of problem where the flexibility of `zref` may be useful. With it, we can just set a new property to store with the label, to refer to it later on. One big advantage of this is that we don't need a special label command just for this case. It is also simpler.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
% To match your options.
\zcsetup{
  nameinlink=false,
  cap=true,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{subthm}{(\arabic{\@enumctr})}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/before}{
  \tl_if_eq:NnT \@currenvir {theorem}
    {
      \AddToHookNext{env/enumerate/begin}{
        \zcsetup{reftype=theorem}
        \zref@localaddprop{main}{subthm}
      }
    }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\zlabel{thm:theorem}
This theorem contains some items
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\arabic*),ref=\thetheorem(\arabic*)]
  \item \zlabel{thm:theorem_1}
    This is the first item.

  \item \zlabel{thm:theorem_2}
    This is the second item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
We can prove \zcref[ref=subthm,noname]{thm:theorem_1}.
\end{proof}

In \zcref{thm:theorem} we have \zcref{thm:theorem_1,thm:theorem_2}.

Also \zcref[noname]{thm:theorem} and \zcref[noname]{thm:theorem_1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this code. Very easy to write and very clear. But there are some differences with what I would like to be the result. 1. I want the theorem name only outside the proof, I did not find a way to give a specific reftype to each property. 2. the last line has no link. Thank you anyway, I did not know this package.

Comment: @LucaBenatti As to 1., I'm not sure I understand. About 2., that's what plain `zref` offers, if you want a link but no name, you can use `\zcref[noname]{label}`. Which, as far as I understood, may also be what you want in 1.